What does a one form $d\theta$ on $S^1$ do to $v \in T_p(S^1)$?
Consider a $1$- form $\omega$ on $\mathbb R^2-0$ given by
$\omega=\frac{x dy - y dx} {x^2+y^2} $ and consider parameterization of $S^1$ as $(\cos \theta, \sin \theta) $. Consider the inclusion $i:S^1\to \mathbb R^2-0 $.
The pullback $i^\ast\omega=(\cos^2 \theta +\sin^2\theta) d\theta=d\theta$ gives a $1$- form on $S^1$.
Question: Suppose that $v\in T_p S^1=$ the set of all derivations near $p$, then what is $d\theta (v) $?
On $\mathbb R^2$, for example, if $v=(v_1,v_2)\in \mathbb R^2$,then $dx(v) = v_1$.

In polar coordinates $(r,\theta)$ the situation is similar.  Any tangent vector is decomposed as a combination of $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}$.  One has $d\theta(\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta})=1$, etc.

If $p\neq-1$ and $\phi:(-1,1)\to S^1\setminus\{-1\},t\mapsto\exp(\pi i t)$ then the derivation $\alpha\in T_pS^1$ is mapped by $d\theta$ to $\pi \cdot dx(\alpha\circ\phi^{-1})=\pi\cdot\alpha(\phi^{-1})$. Just because $\phi^\ast(d\theta)=\pi\cdot dx$. Transform to local coordinates! $T_pS^1$ is one dimensional anyway, and $d\theta$ just picks out the scalar component (or a multiple of it) of any element of $T_pS^1$ up to a choice of identification, choice of basis.
